# WiX install C++ redistributable in msi

Tags: wix, windows-installer

Following on from my last question [Why does my WiX Custom action throw a System.IO.FileNotFoundException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15246037/why-does-my-wix-custom-action-throw-a-system-io-filenotfoundexception), I am now trying to get the C++ distributable installed as part of my msi.

I have followed the example as per the documentation; http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/install_vcredist.htm

```
<DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR">
      <Merge Id="VC_Redist" SourceFile="$(env.ProgramFiles)\Common Files\Merge Modules\Microsoft_VC100_CRT_x86.msm" DiskId="1" Language="0"/>
    </DirectoryRef>

    <Feature Id="Complete" Level="1" Title="$(var.NVRProduct) $(var.NVRVersion)" Description="Everything" Display="expand">
      <Feature Id="VC_Redist" Title="Visual C++ Runtime" AllowAdvertise="no" Display="hidden" Level="1">
        <MergeRef Id="VC_Redist"/>
      </Feature>      
    </Feature>
```

It does not work. The C++ distributable is not installed, and subsequently my msi throws an error as the C++ distribution is missing, and uninstalls itself.

This seems to be the same as this question, which was not really answered. 
[C++ Redistributable package with WIX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11262209/c-redistributable-package-with-wix)

Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am going to answer my own question as there are a number of issues I found out after further investigation.

Firstly, the install of the VC++ merged module was actually working!

I didn't think it was because I was still getting an error, and I couldn't see an entry for the VC++ runtime in the Add Remove programs like you can if you install it manually.

However, by changing the installation to only install the distributables and the application up to where I received the error, I could see the VC++ dll was actually being installed. The error I was now seeing was because the program required the ATL redistibutable as well. (As I discovered through using Dependency Walker). The error caused the msi to fail, and the VC++ dll was being uninstalled along with the rest of my application dlls!

Once I provided the VC++ and the ATL distributables using the mechanism as per the example in the help file, all was well.

I have also used the statically linked SQLite dll as even with the distributables being installed, the initial calls to SQLite from the custom action were failing. I think this must be due to an installation sequence issue. However, using the statically linked version has raised a degree of discussion among developers here, with around a 50-50 split in favour and strongly against using it.

The installation does now work, however.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your custom action is either scheduled before the InstallFiles action or not deferred or both. You don't provide the custom action definition but make sure your `CustomAction` element has the `Execute` attribute set to `'deferred'` and ensure your `Custom` element is in the `InstallExecuteSequence` scheduled `After='InstallFiles'`.

Alternatively, you might consider statically linking the CRT into your custom action. I always recommend this option since it makes your custom action stand alone which greatly increases the chance that the custom action will always work (including during install, repair, uninstall, and patching).